# Is the mean difference between two groups a relative treatment effect?

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, effect-size, risk-difference, absolute-risk

In randomized trials, I know that treatment effects such as the odds ratios, relative risks and hazard ratios are considered relative treatment effects.

What about the following effect sizes?
a. Mean differences
b. ratio of means
c. risk differences
d. Arcsine differences